# How to skip last 2 records and get all other records with linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table called **Test**:

```
Test: Id, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
```

Now I want to get list of test but `skip last 2 test`. So if I have say for e.g. `10 test` then I want to get  **1 -  8 test and skip test 9 and 10**.

This is how I am trying to do that:

```
var query = context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id).Skip(2) // How to take other records?
```

Comment: `var query = context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id).Skip(2).Take(8);`

Comment: @Leopard:That was just an example and records size is not fixed

Comment: Skip() returns all remaining elements as ienumerable. therefore you can use `context.Test.Take(context.Test.Count() - 2);` or `context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id).Skip(2);` Both methods return the same elements. The last one in a different order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case: `Take(8)`

With [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) you can get any range you want.

E.G:

```
var query = context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id);
var allButTheLastTwoElements = query.Take(query.Count() - 2);
```

Safest way:

```
var query = context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id).ToList();
var allButTheLastTwoElements = query.Take(Math.Max(0,query.Count() - 2));
```

Or you could just do it the other way around (depending on your requirements)

```
var query = context.Test.OrderByAscending(t=>t.Id).Skip(2);
```

Comment: That was just an example and records size is not fixed

Comment: Well, you'll just have to calculate the number of elements. You also have a [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: So i need to get count with another context and use it in take method??

Comment: No, use the same context (the same query in fact). Or you get all elements (with a `ToList()` for example) and skip the last two.

Comment: Thank you so much but your safest query will load all data in memory and then it will filter out hence i am using last query .Once again thank you so much for your kind help :)

Answer (score 6):

If records size is not fixed, you would use:

```
test.Take(test.Count-2);
//If records are already sorted in the order you like,
```

or

```
test.Where(t=>t.ID <= test.Max(m=>m.ID)-2);
//Where ID is a unique key and the list may not be sorted by id
//This will return the lowest 8 ID even if the list is sorted by address or whatever.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is very simple, you don't even need to use `Take` or query the database twice.

If you `OrderByDescending` and `Skip` the first **N** elements, then you're taking all the remaining elements by default. So you can just do this:

```
var query = context.Test.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Id).Skip(2);
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
>   the remaining elements.

If you don't really intend to deffer the execution or append additional querying logic, then calling `.ToList()` at the end (which actually executes the query against the database) is logical.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: This will sort your list by ID descending - forcing you to re-sort if you want to sort by name or address or whatever. Use my WHERE() example to get lowest 8 records while maintaining your intended sort order.